# Add new property inside interface object without changing class in typescript dynamically

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a class as below.

```
export class Cars implements Vehicales {
    color?: string;
    type?: string[];
}
```

Due to some reason I cannot modify my above export object.
And the templates object is passed to kendoReactGrid where it contains all the strings for the columns and I need to add it inside my interface only and not the export object.

I have an interface as below

```
interface CarpProps {
    templates: Cars[]
}
```

Now I want to add an additional property `tyreCount: string[]` to my templates object.
How can i do that in typescript interface?
I tried during extends keyword but was not successfull.
I am new to typescript any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extends keyword instead of `implements` and add the additional property by creating Cards as an interface too

```
export interface Cars extends Vehicales {
    color?: string;
    type?: string[];
    tyreCount: string[]
}
```

and use it like

```
interface CarpProps {
    templates: Cars[]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but due to some reason I cannot modify my export object.
And the templates object is passed to kendoReactGrid where it contains all the strings for the columns and I need to add it inside my templates - interface only and not the export object.

Is there any work around for this....to add new property to interface?